# How to get source of openjdk-8-jdk with patches applied?

Tags: java, ubuntu, debian, patch, quilt

I have run `apt-get source openjdk-8-jdk=8u275-b01-0ubuntu1~18.04`.

which gathered `.dsc`, `.orig.tar.gz` file and `.diff.gz` files, which I deleted afterwards.
Next to these files is a folder `openjdk-8-8u275-b01` which contains a `debian/patches/` folder.
Inside the patches folder is a list `.diff` and `.patch` files, however no `order` file.

I need to get the source of openjdk-8-jdk and that specific version with the patches applied.

Running `quilt push -a` returns an error `No series file found.`

Running `apt-get source openjdk-8-jdk=8u275-b01-0ubuntu1~18.04` again throws an error as that version is no longer available.
The files can however still be downloaded from [https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-8/8u275-b01-0ubuntu1~18.04](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-8/8u275-b01-0ubuntu1%7E18.04)

How do I get the patched source?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to spec: https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/modify.en.html

Basically you create shell alias `dquilt` with special env var that follows convention of Debian project, the most important is:

```
QUILT_PATCHES="debian/patches"
```

Then you can `quilt push -a`.

Comment: Even with the steps followed I get the same error "No series file found.".